# adding characters in a string multiple times

Tags: php, string, loops

I want to separate numbers by a space, in sets of 4. e.g. 1234567890, would become 1234 5678 90

I managed to create a script to achieve this, but it seems over the top, is there any easier way of achieving this?

```
$num = 23853267362365;
$count = strlen($num)/4;

$new_num = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++) {
    $num_len = strlen($num);
    if($num_len>4) {
        $new_num[] = substr($num,0,4);
        $num = substr($num,4,$num_len-4);
    }
}

$num = implode(' ',$new_num);
```

Comment: `preg_replace('/(\d{4})/', '$1 ', $str)`?

Comment: @MarcB: If string is divisible by 4 you'll get a trailing space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chunk_split()`:

```
echo chunk_split(1234567890, 4, ' ');
```

Link: http://php.net/manual/function.chunk-split.php

Answer (score 0):

A non `chunk_split()` answer; not as good as Jessie Jackson's answer but is adaptable to any chunk length.

```
$start_num = 23853267362365;
$chunk_length = 4; // change to whatever length you need
$count = ceil(strlen($num) / $chunk_length);

$concat =''; // initiate
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
   $concat .= substr($start_num, ($chunk_length * $x), $chunk_length) . ' ';
}

$new_num = rtrim($concat, ' ');
```