# How to Split my values into 10 digits

Tags: php

I get all mobile numbers from `database` and convert into string. Next for to split my mobile numbers into 10,10 digits.

```
  <?php
      $query = mysql_query("select phone from reservation");
      $array = array();
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){           
          $test = $row['phone'];
          $test_sp=(string)$test;//convert into string
          $arr=str_split($test_sp, "10"); //break up into every 10digits
          $new_test=implode(",",$arr);
          echo $new_test;
      }
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
`994417626199441762619944176261`
```

Expecting Output:

```
`9944176261,9944176261,9944176261`
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on php 5.6+: https://eval.in/642244. What version are you using? You can probably solve it by changing `"10"` to `10`.

Comment: mine 5.4.16 . yes i check out your link its working. but in my version cloud not run this script. problem is not version.while copy the code run in my system its working. The problem behind in fetch date from `db` @jeroen

Comment: how to add ' '  for string?

Comment: Use `chunk_split()` function. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479453/adding-characters-in-a-string-multiple-times